# Comparing two dataframes using multiple conditions with groupby and filter function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have two dataframes, each containing data values and months (these are the relevant columns). The second dataframe also contains TMIN (minimum) and TMAX (maximum) values listed under the Element column.

The first dataframe has 12 entries showing the maximum temperatures that occurred in a given month between 2005- 2014. Let's call this df_max

The second dataframe shows temperatures that occurred after the the 2014 cutoff date. Let's call this df_2.

I would like to create a third dataframe that shows temperatures in df2 that exceed the temperatures in df_max grouped by the month.

These are the values in df_max

```
        Data_Value
Month   
1.0   217.0
2.0   194.0
3.0   317.0
4.0   306.0
5.0   367.0
6.0   406.0
7.0   406.0
8.0   372.0
9.0   372.0
10.0    328.0
11.0    256.0
12.0    194.0
```

These are some of the values in df2:

```
ID  Date    Element Data_Value  Month
19  USC00205563 2015-01-03  TMIN    -39 1
30  USC00203712 2015-03-17  TMAX    800 3
34  USC00200032 2015-06-06  TMIN    128 6
46  USW00014833 2015-08-30  TMIN    178 8
50  USC00202308 2015-08-30  TMIN    156 8
51  USC00205563 2015-01-03  TMAX    22  1
59  USC00202308 2015-08-30  TMAX    600 8
72  USC00200230 2015-04-01  TMIN    -17 4
126 USC00200032 2015-06-06  TMAX    233 6
139 USW00014853 2015-05-17  TMIN    183 5
146 USC00208972 2015-04-09  TMAX    67  4
155 USC00205050 2015-01-05  TMIN    -139    1
157 USC00200230 2015-04-01  TMAX    183 4
170 USC00203712 2015-03-17  TMIN    11  3
179 USC00208972 2015-05-27  TMAX    500 5
```

I think that I should first groupby the element value to zero in on TMAX temperatures and by month and then filter the values to only focus on those that are greater than the max of each month in df_max. This is the code I have:

```
df3 = df2[df2['Element'] =='TMAX'].groupby[('Month')('Data_Value')].filter(lambda x: x > df_max['Data_Value'])
```

This returns the error message 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'

**Desired Outcome**

So my desired outcome is: for example assume df2 has i.) 3 rows falling under month 2 and their values are 800, 400 and 150. ii) 4 rows falling under month 5 with values 100, 500, 700, 300 and 100.

The new dataframe (df3) would;
i.) contain the rows 800 and 400, as they exceed the 194 maximum value in df_max that corresponds with month 2.
ii.) contain the rows 500 and 700 as these exceed the 367 value in df_max that corresponds with month 5.

**Update**
In order to find all the values in df2 that may exceed the max of each month in df_max, I decided to use groupby and nlargest to identify the top 3 temperatures for each month with the assumption (based on observing the dataset) that only the top 3 would exceed the max per month in df_max. The problem though is that the output is in pd.series format and I'm not sure how to compare the values for each month with the values in the df_max dataframe.

Here is the code I wrote

```
df3 = df2[df2['Element'] =='TMAX'].groupby("Month")["Data_Value"].nlargest(3)

#find values in df3 that exceed the maximum temperatures in df_max for each month in the year
df3_max = df3[df3.Data_Value >= df_max.Data_Value]
```

However, I get the error message: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Data_Value'

Comment: `.groupby[('Month')('Data_Value')]` is not good syntax. Maybe `.groupby['Month','Data_Value']` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2.groupby('Month').agg({'Data_Value':'max'}).reset_index(), 
                on = 'Month', how='inner')
df3[df3.Data_Value_x > df3.Data_Value_y]

   Month  Data_Value_x  Data_Value_y
0     1         217.0            22
2     4         306.0           183
4     6         406.0           233
```

Comment: Yes, it is quite more inefficient after all, thx for suggestion

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but won't this find the maximum value per month of df2 values and only return the values that are greater than the df_min month equivalent? Maybe I worded my question wrongly because I am trying to for example find the values in month 2(df2) that are lower than the df_min month 2 value and add those values to df3 (for all 12 months)

Comment: Please could you share the expected ouput of your example? That way it'll be much easier

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful but for example assume df2 has i.) 3 rows falling under month 2 and their values are 800, 400 and 150. ii) 4 rows falling under month 5 with values 100, 500, 700, 300 and 100. df3 would contain the values 800 and 400 (as they exceed the 194 maximum value in df_max) and (500 and 700) as these exceed the 367 value in df_max. Hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you want.

```
df3 = df2[df2['Element'] =='TMAX'].groupby("Month").max()
df3 = df3[df3.Data_value == df_max.Data_Value.max()]
```

I think, code is self-explanatory code.

Comment: Thanks  but for example, I am trying to find all the values in month 2 (in df2) that are lower than the df_min month 2 value...I would like to do this for all 12 months –